# React native (Expo) project shows "cant find variable : require"

Tags: react-native, expo, metro-bundler

I am an intermediate react developer.
I was running my react native app peacefully without any problems untill one morning, i did not change anything in my codebase but when i tried to run the app through expo client, it started showing the error in the screenshot.

I have checked and checked this platform, and not a single solution.

I am currently using expo sdk 43 (managed workflow) please help...this is my first time posting here.

This is the error below;

```
Can't find variable: require


http://127.0.0.1:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:5:24.globalcode@http://127.0.0.1:19000/node_modules /expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true& hot=false&minify=false:720:3.
```

[Click here for the screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUyWh.png)

Comment: Please write the error message in your question. Do you have require() somewhere in your codebase?

Comment: I made changes to the question like you requested

Comment: **Yes but do you have `require` somewhere in your code?** Also try creating a new app with `expo init` paste your `package.json`, run `npm install`copy your code base and tell me if it works now.

Comment: No my bro ...there is no require in my code base ...i only do imports

Comment: Try deleting node_modules and running `npm install`

Comment: I have done that over and over again ...i even cleared cache.....i also tried a new project with "expo init" and surprisingly, the same error even on a fresh project ..wow!...i am dumbfounded, my code was working perfectly well just 1day ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed.

See what i did,
I created a fresh expo project using "expo init"

Then copied all my files into the new project "except node_modules and .expo folders".

Then i ran "npm install"

Viola!!! Everything works fine now

Note: i tried removing "node_modules" before over and over again and it dint work.

The only thing that worked was starting a new project and following the above steps.